# Sum of numbers from 1 to 5 in loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

To simplify my scenario, I am redefining my question here.

I want to add numbers from 1 to 5 in loop. X should be 1,2,3,4,5. and start with Y as 0. Y = X + Y should give the sum of 1 through 5.

Requirement: I want to start y as 0 and want y to hold latest add_sum value.

Expected output:

```
    1st iteration: y = 1 (x = 1, y = 0)

    2st iteration: y = 3 (x = 2, y = 1)

    3st iteration: y = 6 (x = 3, y = 3)

    ...

    ...

    so on
```

I am new to python coding, Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: this can't be all of your code, how are you running the program ?

Comment: this is just a snippet of what i want.

Comment: your functions aren't even declared correctly

Comment: if you want help you should provide the code where you ran into your "issue"

Comment: Also, your print function isn't showing the result of the variable. It works for me when I fix the syntax. Also, it's not going to go 10 iterations with range(1,5). Are you sure it's not just that you aren't printing the value of y?

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, range(6))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, fixing your syntax and running your code seems to work just fine.

```
def read_num():
    for num in range (1,5):
        x = num
        add_sum(x)


def add_sum(x):
    global y
    y = x + y
        print ("y =", y)

y = 0
read_num()
```

If you want x to be 1 thru 5 **inclusive**, you have to use `range(1,6)` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
y = 0  # Assign value 0 to variable 'y'
for x in xrange(1, 6):  # Cycle from 1 to 5 and assign it to variable x using iterator as we need just 1 value at a time
  print '(x=%s, y=%s)' % (x, y)  # Display value of 'x' & 'y' variables to user for debug & learning purpose
  y += x  # Adding x to the y.
  print 'y=%s' % y  # Display result of sum accumulated in variable 'y'
```

Edit: added comments to the code as requested in comments.

Comment: Please add some code comments and explanations to your answer.

Comment: Really? This is the most simple code I've eve seen apart from "print HelloWorld". Are you joking? Added some comments for your pleasure.

Comment: Your answer poped up in my review queue as a 'low quality answer' for deletion. I'm no friend of code only answers especially when the OP states he is new to Python. So an explanation for xrange and/or iterators would be nice, because there is no pure for-loop in Python as provided by other languages!

Comment: OK, may be it make sense. Sorry for some sarcasm.